# How to set Java -version is returning jdk instead if java

Tags: java, macos, java-8

Hello I installed java on my MacOS but its not working as expected.

When I do `java -version` below is the output I am getting instead of right version number:

```
abc@xxxxx ~ % java -version
openjdk version "15" 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I see this is want installed under system and user:

[image]

[image]

**Expected Output:**

```
1234$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What's your path? Obviously the OpenJDK version is found first.

Comment: Below is the Java path:
`
xxxx /usr % /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home
`

Comment: ... What's your `$PATH`? OpenJDK is on that path before the version you think you should be getting.

Comment: Current path
//echo $PATH:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: So your `$PATH` either (a) does not include the path to the Java you want, or (b) the OpenJDK version is found first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should fix your `JAVA_HOME`.

Here's the easiest way I know. Just add this to your `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshenv`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/path/to/your/java)"
```

Then restart your terminals/IDEs.